# Modeling MultiTenant in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have several customers each represented by a "tenant"

I would like to know what is the best way to modelize this concept. I did a lot of research and found this topic : http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Modeling-multi-tenanted-Cassandra-schema-td7591311.html

I know there are several possibilities

1. One keyspace by tenant
2. One table (column family) by tenant
3. One field represented the tenant in all tables

I choose the solution 3 but I'm not sure to have the best schema for the best performances

This is my profile schema

```
CREATE TABLE profiles (
  id timeuuid,
  tenant text,
  email text,
  datasources set<text>,
  info map<text, text>,
  friends set<timeuuid>,
  PRIMARY KEY(id, tenant)
);

CREATE INDEX ON profiles(datasources);
CREATE INDEX ON profiles(email);
```

My PARTITION KEY is "id" for the uniqueness and CLUSTERING KEY "tenant".
My need is to be able to execute this queries as quickly as possible

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id = x
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = x
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE email = x
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE datasources CONTAINS x
```

Queries are OK but I wondered if it would be better to have "tenant" as PARTITION KEY instead of "id", and use "id" as CLUSTERING KEY

```
CREATE TABLE profiles (
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY(tenant, id)
);
```

In my application "tenant" is always a required field so make the same queries in this way would not be a problem (but is it faster or slower ?)

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = y
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = y AND id = x
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = y AND email = x
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = y AND datasources CONTAINS x
```

*Bonus advantage: the ability to sort profiles by creation date (ORDER BY id)*

Using tenant as PARTITION KEY if I understand well, Cassandra will physically store all elements of the same tenant in the same row and would be potentially able to store up to 2 billion data in this row, in this case what would happen if one of my customers in excess of that number ? I also read we could use a composite key for example by putting the current date (20150313) in the second part of the key to group in one row only all new profiles of the day for the tenant

```
CREATE TABLE profiles (
  ...
  date text,
  PRIMARY KEY((tenant, date), id)
);
```

but with this solution no query is possible to query all data (without date in query).

Also as you can see in my schema I use secondary index for "email" and "datasources" fields. But I read here http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html that using secondary index on a huge table that returns a small number of results (one in my case) was a bad practice. In my schema "datasources" is a set containing for exemple facebookId, twitterId etc

**If you have any ideas I'm really interested :) ! I'm pretty new with Cassandra if there are things I do not understand please tell me**

thanks,

Donovan

Comment: I'm considering something similar to option 1, but where each tenant has a list of applications, and each application has its own keyspace. Which option did you pick? Are you happy with the choice?

Comment: What I find appealing about the first option is the capability to control replication per-app.

Answer (score 0):

Data duplication with Cassandra is not a problem, so you have to think the data modelling process starting with your queries.

So, I'm thinking about something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE profiles (
   id timeuuid,
   tenant text,
   email text,
   datasources set<text>,
   info map<text, text>,
   friends set<timeuuid>,
   PRIMARY KEY((id, tenant))
);
```

Assuming that tenant is known at the application level, this mode will give you the following queries run fast:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id = x and tenant = y


CREATE TABLE profiles_emails (
   id timeuuid,
   tenant text,
   email text,
   datasources set<text>,
   info map<text, text>,
   friends set<timeuuid>,
   PRIMARY KEY((email, tenant))
```

);

```
SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE email = x and tenant = y


CREATE TABLE profiles_tenants (
   id timeuuid,
   tenant text,
   email text,
   datasources set<text>,
   info map<text, text>,
   friends set<timeuuid>,
   PRIMARY KEY((tenant, id))
);

SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = x and id = y

CREATE TABLE tenants (
   id timeuuid,
   tenant text,
   email text,
   datasources set<text>,
   info map<text, text>,
   friends set<timeuuid>,
   PRIMARY KEY((tenant, date))
 );

 SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE tenant = x and date < y
```

or you may look to http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html

For "datasources" based search, you may use a different system like elasticsearch or solr. Or if the set is limited in values, then you may maintain a separate table for each of it.

Cassandra is fast at write operation, data duplication is not a problem, so you may write to all those tables in a batch.

You have also to take in consideration the consistency level, it has an impact on READ performance. Really depending on your use-case.